# Importing a third-party library in an angular2 app

Tags: angular

I would like to know what the best practices are regarding importing a third-party library in an **angular2** application.

As of now I use the following way to import the library:

```
import * as TPL from 'thirdPartyLib';
```

in each of the files of my application that use the third party library.

(The third party library could be anything here from **ramda** or **lodash** to **momentjs**)

What is the impact on the final size of the application bearing in mind I do this in several files and that I only use some of the functions of the third party library? Also my app is made up of several angular modules.

More importantly: are there better ways? Can I and should I import a 3rd party library globally?

Comment: you can simply refer them into the index.html and its available globally

Comment: Thanks. Is it really a good practice?

Comment: instead of having them separately as import statements this is a good practice

Comment: @Aravind When did using globals in modular environment become a 'good practice'?

Comment: Its a personal thought nothing is a best practice common to all

Comment: It doesn't matter if only some functions are used or all of them - unless the library was written with tree-shaking in mind (usually it wasn't). As for Lodash, `lodash.*` packages can be use to decrease the footprint.

Comment: Does it have an impact on my application' size when whether I import a given third-party dependency **once** or **N** times?